# subset pandas dataframe to get specific number of rows based on values in another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe as follows:

```
df1

  site_id       date hour  reach                                  maid
0    16002 2023-09-02   21    NaN  33f9fad6-20c5-426c-962f-bc2fbb82aecb
1    16002 2023-09-04   17    NaN  33f9fad6-20c5-426c-962f-bc2fbb82aecb
2    16002 2023-09-04   19    NaN  4a676aeb-6f6f-4622-934b-59b8f149aad7
3    16002 2023-09-04   17    NaN  35363191-c6aa-49fb-beb1-04a98898bed2
4    16002 2023-09-03   22    NaN  a44beb20-a90a-4135-be18-6dda71eeb7c2
```

I have created another dataframe based on the above dataframe that provides the count of records for each `[site_id,date,hour]` combination.  T

```
df2

      site_id       date hour  count
1666    37226 2023-09-02    8   4586
1676    37226 2023-09-03   16   3586
639     36972 2023-09-03   21   235
640     36972 2023-09-03   22   5431
641     36972 2023-09-03   23   343
```

I want to filter the first data frame and get exact number of records as given in the `count` column of second data frame.  For example, I want to get the `4586` records from the first data frame matching the `site_id 37226, date 2023-09-02 and hour 8`.

I tried using a forloop on the second dataframe as follows:

```
for index,rows in k3.iterrows():
    sid=rows['site_id']
    dt=rows['date']
    hr=rows['hour']
    cnt=rows['count']
    kdf1=dff[(dff['site_id'] == sid) & (dff['date']==dt) & (dff['hour']==hr)]   
    kdf2=kdf1[:cnt]
```

This works - but works extremely slow.  Is there a faster method to get the subset.  I am also attaching herewith the links to both sample dataframes:

[Link to df1 and df2](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1_r4WfSzeBrzv6bR8hr6PWmvKTG_496sE?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can merge the `count` from `df2` to `df1`, and then using `.groupby` to reduce the count of groups:

```py
cols = ["site_id", "date", "hour"]


df1 = df1.merge(df2, on=cols, how="right")
df1 = df1.groupby(cols, group_keys=False).apply(lambda x: x[: x["count"].iloc[0]])
df1.pop("count")

print(df1.head())
```

Prints:

```
   site_id        date  hour  reach                                  maid
0    37221  2023-09-03    19    NaN  3e769e74-9129-49ba-838d-c36f3a9b3335
1    37221  2023-09-03    19    NaN  71e258d2-5155-4001-9b3c-02a1a1f9c9fb
2    37221  2023-09-03    19    NaN  92eaee88-b41c-4999-b1b8-6be183e5d2cf
3    37221  2023-09-03    19    NaN  c6eb504a-9259-410b-8391-7b06b3e92a41
4    37221  2023-09-03    19    NaN  c36400ff-0790-4844-b58b-2e4cdaafb4d9
```

Note: With your data this method takes ~0.15 seconds, your original version ~11.2 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Add a sequential counter per group using `cumcount` then `merge` the dataframes and filter the rows where the value of counter is less than required count

```
c = ['site_id', 'date', 'hour']

df1['rnum'] = df1.groupby(c).cumcount().add(1)
result = df1.merge(df2, how='left', on=c).query('rnum <= count')
```

---

```
   site_id        date  hour  reach                                  maid  rnum  count
0    16002  2023-09-02    21    NaN  33f9fad6-20c5-426c-962f-bc2fbb82aecb     1     71
1    16002  2023-09-04    17    NaN  33f9fad6-20c5-426c-962f-bc2fbb82aecb     1     40
2    16002  2023-09-04    19    NaN  4a676aeb-6f6f-4622-934b-59b8f149aad7     1     50
3    16002  2023-09-04    17    NaN  35363191-c6aa-49fb-beb1-04a98898bed2     2     40
4    16002  2023-09-03    22    NaN  a44beb20-a90a-4135-be18-6dda71eeb7c2     1     61
5    16002  2023-09-02     8    NaN  37dfb047-c058-409b-aa3a-24e2e5c03f35     1     32
6    16002  2023-09-02    11    NaN  37dfb047-c058-409b-aa3a-24e2e5c03f35     1     54
7    16002  2023-09-03    10    NaN  f52924a8-c487-4355-9e67-aa8392c4635a     1     45
8    16002  2023-09-04    21    NaN  7c41c274-da15-4d8b-bcde-da0ee7bb7566     1     44
9    16002  2023-09-03    14    NaN  7c41c274-da15-4d8b-bcde-da0ee7bb7566     1     58
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  The `cumcount()` is a new function until me and I think I will find a lot of usage in my day today work.  Thank you again.